# opening lightning component via onrowaction in the same page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to open a lightning component via a button in onrowaction.
If I do so, it'll open in another tab which I dont want. I would like it to open in the same page.

[image]
[image]

this is the code I have.

```
var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
            evt.setParams({
                componentDef : "c:SendEmail",
                componentAttributes: {
                    "recordId" : row.EmailMessageId
                }
            });
            evt.fire();
```

can somebody help please?

thank you!

Comment: you can try adding the lightning component 'SendEmail' in the same parent component and display it as a modal, so that it pops up in the same page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. finaly I could manage to close the component using workspaceAPI which was Okay as a work around.